# Conditional expectation: Sum of normal and uniform

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I have a pretty easy question that I keep making a hash of.

Suppose that you observe $\overline{F} = F + \epsilon$. Here F ~ Unif(0,2) and $\epsilon \sim$ Normal(0,0.2) is a normally distributed error term. $F,\epsilon$ are independent.

I'd like to find the conditional expectation $E[F | \overline{F} = k]$ for arbitrary k. Can you help me work this out?

[[**Edit**: Here's where I'm stuck]]

We have \begin{equation} \begin{split} E[F|\overline{F}=k] & = \int_{x = -\infty}^{x = \infty}\frac{f_{F,\overline{F}}(x,k)}{f_{\overline{F}}(k)}xdx \\ &= \int_{x=0}^{x=2}\frac{f_{F,\epsilon}(x,k-x)}{f_{F+\epsilon}(k)}xdx \\ & = \int_{x=0}^{x=2} \frac{f_F(x)f_\epsilon(k-x)}{\int_{y=0}^2 f_F(y)f_{\epsilon}(k-y)}xdx\end{split} \end{equation}

But since $f_F = 1/2$ in [0,2] we have:

\begin{equation} \begin{split} E[F|\overline{F}=k] & =  \int_{x=0}^2 \frac{f_\epsilon(k-x)}{\int_{y=0}^2 f_{\epsilon}dy}xdx \end{split} \end{equation}

And we should be able to solve this by putting \begin{equation} f_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{0.2^2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(1/2)(x/0.2^2)^2} \end{equation}

But every time I try it I get a mess. I don't think it's just me. I plugged this into Wolfram Alpha and got 0!

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y$ is $f_{X \mid Y=y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, where the denominator is $f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx$.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some information about where I'm stuck -- I think I got stuck a bit further on?